# Jersey 1.17 on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, rest, jersey

I deployed my REST service on Google App Engine and I receive following error each time I try to query the service:

```
com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory __getComponentProvider: The provider class, class com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.MimeMultipartProvider, could not be instantiated. Processing will continue but the class will not be utilized
java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to get members for class com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.MimeMultipartProvider
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-7d6711107bb7eaaa(Request.java)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:253)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.MethodList.getAllDeclaredMethods(MethodList.java:70)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.MethodList.<init>(MethodList.java:64)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.getPostConstructMethods(ComponentConstructor.java:131)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.<init>(ComponentConstructor.java:123)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.__getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:137)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getComponent(ProviderServices.java:256)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getServices(ProviderServices.java:160)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBodyFactory.java:176)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:162)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1310)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:168)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:774)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:770)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:770)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:765)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:489)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:319)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:454)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:461)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:703)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:338)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:330)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:458)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/MessagingException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2444)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.MessagingException
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-7d6711107bb7eaaa(Request.java)
    ... 41 more
```

This service doesn't use or send any mail messages. Only one thing it does is writing JSON response from some POJO. It works locally of course (on local GAE and local Tomcat).

Answer (score 1):

It might be a compatibility problem with versions. According to [**this**](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava), Jersey versions that are compatible with Google App Engine are 1.5 and 1.1.5.

I had similar problems and I don't like this version compatibility issues, so I opted for:

- To offer REST web services from GAE, use [**Google Cloud Endpoints**](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/), which is still an experimental technology but as far as I've tried, it works pretty well. Furthermore it is very well integrated with GAE and the [**Google Plugin for Eclipse**](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/cloud_endpoints?hl=es).
- To cosume REST services from GAE, I've opted for using just Java build-in HTTP client library as explained [**here**](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/usingjavanet). I don't know if it's the best way, but it is very simple and you avoid compatibility problems that could arise between GAE and external APIs such as Jersey.

Comment: You're wellcome! I think it's a good idea to use as many Google's APIs and tools as you can when developing in GAE... i.e. Gson for JSON, google-oauth-java-client for OAuth, etc...

Comment: I'd rather search cloud where it'll be work. I test CloudBees now and it seems it works.

Comment: This information is not valid anymore!!!

I used Jersey 1.17.1 without any hacks in web.xml

Answer (score 0):

I created a GAE REST skeleton app on GitHub.  It's at https://github.com/deege/gae-rest-skeleton

The app just has two REST calls defined, but it will give you a starting point.  It uses GAE 1.9.4, and Jersey 1.17.1.

You can fork the code from https://github.com/deege/gae-rest-skeleton.git